# jquery attribute selector on collection

Tags: jquery, attributes

So if I were to do this $('.my_class[href]'), this should return to me all the elements in the page with class 'my_class' that has attribute 'href'.

Could I get to the same result if I have a variable with the value $('.my_class')? How do I filter only those elements in that variable with those who have attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function:

```
var elements = $('.my_class');
var filtered = elements.filter('[href]');
```